# D3.js: Trying to build flat calendar

Tags: javascript, d3.js, calendar

Newbie here.I am trying to build a horizontal calendar to indicate people on vacations. I have placed the mockup below with annotation of key feature, I'm trying to incorporate.

[image]

- Legend Y - Indicates the person
- Legend X - Indicates the Month and year.
- Each cell is color coded based on holiday or vacation or weekend.
- The calendar part (not including legend area) should be draggable.

I have got rough implementation going...I am able to get the first horizontal calendar,
Code: http://jsbin.com/xumabavo/1/edit

- Is my approach correct?
- how to stack each other?
- How to enable dragging and render dates before and after the window?

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

---

*Is my approach correct?*

Yes. Mockup is crucial. Prototype as well. It looks to me that you have confidence, determination, and intelligence necessary for this project.

---

*How to stack each other?*

I gather you will get overall data as an array of individual data specific for particular person. You can use index of that array (index corresponds to a person) to shift all visual elements to the appropriate row - in other words, to stack the data. Callback functions can have two parameters d (data) and i (index), something like this:

```
  .style( "background-color", function( d, i ) {
    // d is datum being rendered
    // i is datum's index in dataset
    // return value based on logic
  } )
```

---

*How to enable dragging and render dates before and after the window?*

It seems to me you would benefit from analyzing this small app: [link](http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/1962173)

[image]